# Angular 2: Inject Service to another service. (No provider error)

Tags: angular

I want to inject a service to another service:

```
@Injectable()

export class Dispatcher {
}


@Injectable()

export class TodoStore {

    constructor(@Inject(Dispatcher) dispatcher:Dispatcher){ 

    }
}
```

But I always get Error:  No provider for Dispatcher!

Comment: `@Inject(Dispatcher)` is redundant if the parameter type is the same.

Comment: In my setup, you can just import the service like you do in a component then inject the way you have, and it will work. Basically you are just missing the import

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to `provide` your service somewhere. Please refer to [angular2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html)

You could provide it in the bootstrap method:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[TodoStore,Dispatcher]);
```

or the app component:

```
@Component({
    ...
      providers:[TodoStore,Dispatcher]
}
...
```

Or in any other component, depending on your needs.

Also, you don't need to `@Inject(Dispatcher)` in the constructor. It's basically the same as

```
constructor(dispacher:Dispatcher){
}
```

Comment: I still needed the `@Inject(Dispactcher)` in the constructor to make it work.

Comment: What about if the method is called async? you can't access to the one injected into the constructor, you still need to inject it to the method itself, So:  @Inject('Service') service

Comment: @AlejandroLora I am not sure I understood your point correctly. But, I think you are using "this" incorrectly. If my guess is right, your issue is not related to injection. Please refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). If my guess wasn't correct, please provide a plunker with an example of the issue.

Comment: I am confused, where is the bootstrap() method located? In which class?

Answer (score 6):

Thank for the reply.

Since it is not a Component,  the @Component(...) solution does not apply.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[TodoStore,Dispatcher]);
```

solution works.  But that makes this `main.ts` a central place.

Comment: Why do you think the `@Component()` doesn't work? `@Component()` is where you register the provider, it can still be injectec to a service.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  but a service have no @ Component decorator, so if you want to inyect a service inside another service you are forced to include it in the bootstrap(),  why it's possible to specify a provider in a @ component and all his children ; but not in a simple service parent.. with no @ Component decorator, just a simple class. Ex: mock.service.ts: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HEROES }     from './mock-heroes';
@Injectable()
export class MockService {
  getHeroes() { return HEROES;  }
}

Comment: I see. `@Component()` wasn't mentioned in the question, this is why I was wondering why it was mentioned at all in the answer.

Comment: so there is no way to inject an service inside another, just do it like global service in Bootstrap. am I right @GünterZöchbauer ?

Comment: Sure, injecting one service into another just works. Each service needs to be provided somewhere.

Comment: @stackdave the centralization is indeed an issue. Did you find a solutiom?

Bad ng design around this: You encapsulate things in modules only to find that they also must be declared globally, why should the main.ts be aware of my modules behaviour? if a service is injectable into a component, why can't ng2 discover the dependency tree and provide the service automatically with its dependents...

Answer (score 1):

A providers array is available in @NgModule. You can provide your service by declaring your service in that array.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[...],
    imports:[...],
    providers: [MyCustomService],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
```