# How to inject class into Service [Angular 6]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Can we make a class(not service) as shared utility which can be injected into services or even components through angular dependency injection?

*MyUtilClass*

```
export class MyUtilClass{

  do(){
     // something
  }
}
```

*MyService*

```
export class MyService{
  constructor(private uitl:MyUtilClass){
    util.do();
  }
}
```

Comment: Make `MyUtilClass` @Injectable() the same way you are doing with `MyServcie`

Comment: The same way you would any other service as services can be injected into each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Inject Service to another service. (No provider error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152608/angular-2-inject-service-to-another-service-no-provider-error)

Comment: we don't need to add @Injectable decorator if we add the MyUtilClass to providers list , right ? unless we use providedIn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service in angular is just a class so you can inject any class to any class

*Utility*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class Utility {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Utility is created');
  }
}
```

*MyServiceService*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Utility} from './utility'

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class MyServiceService {

  constructor(private uitl:Utility) { }

}
```

> `{providedIn:'root'}` in a feature in angular 6 another way is to add MyServiceService , Utility to providers array in **app.module.ts** in that case you can remove @Injectable decorator in Utility class

[**demo - check the console**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erqkx2)

Answer (score 4):

Services are classes with a bit addition difference(not structurally), they has a decorator @Injectable() not more! And you can make service through angular CLI by running

```
ng generate service service-name
```

it will be injected in your other class.enjoy!

Comment: I want to inject class into service

Answer (score -1):

You can create file e.g. util.ts with your utils and export functions included directly e.g.

```
export function do() {
  //do something
}
```

next it may be imported and used into your service. In the other hand instead of class you can create MyUtilService and provide it into your MyService what is Angular recommended way.

Comment: it's not related to the question