# Angular : Injecting a service into another service

Tags: angular, service, dependencies, angular-providers

I have service1 depending on an other service2.

Service2 has one parameter in its constructor.

When declaring service2 in the constructor of service1 like this

`constructor(private service : service2) {...}`

I have the following error : An argument for service1 is not provided.

The solution here [Angular 2: Inject Service to another service. (No provider error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152608/angular-2-inject-service-to-another-service-no-provider-error/37152720) consisting to put service2 in app.module providers work for my components but not for the service1. I steel have the error : an argument for 'service2' is not provided.

for more details :

Service2 :

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })


  dataSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  list: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
...
}
```

service1 :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FlowsheetEditorService {

  //declarations ...

  // httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  
  constructor(private api : ApiService) { ...}
}
```

In app module :

providers: [ApiService],

bootstrap: [AppComponent]

Do you know why and can you help?

I don't know if that matter but I put all my services in a folder in the /app folder.

Thank you

Comment: Have you added: @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})? Please share a few lines of your code.

Comment: I just updated with the codes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject service into service then inject in customer and use another service function inside service

Comment: Can you develop more please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had initialized the service somewhere in my project without the parameter: which should not be done because angular initializes the services